# Perl - Multithreading script prints memory map and backtrace

Tags: multithreading, perl, memory-management, scripting, threadpool

[image]When I invoke my multithreaded perl script, on a few occassions, it throws some exception similar to the following. I am sorry that I could not share code. But if really needed I can try to build a snippet (if really really required). Because I guess this should have some theoretical answer.

```
*** glibc detected *** perl: double free or corruption (!prev): 0x00007f775401e9a0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3d74c75e66]
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3d74c789b3]
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3d74c7b880]
/lib64/libc.so.6(realloc+0xe5)[0x3d74c7baf5]
/usr/lib/../lib64/libcrypto.so.10(CRYPTO_realloc+0x5f)[0x7f775907bd8f]
/usr/lib/../lib64/libcrypto.so.10(lh_insert+0xee)[0x7f77590f763e]
/usr/lib/../lib64/libcrypto.so.10(OBJ_NAME_add+0x6b)[0x7f775907f12b]
/usr/lib/../lib64/libcrypto.so.10(EVP_add_cipher+0x27)[0x7f7759102387]
/usr/lib/../lib64/libcrypto.so.10(OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers+0x4b7)[0x7f7759106a07]
/usr/lib/../lib64/libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf+0xe)[0x7f775910653e]
/usr/local/lib/libssh2.so.1(libssh2_init+0x39)[0x7f77596800b9]
```

Why am I getting such errors?

I am using use Thread::Queue; use threads::shared; Please let me know your views.

Below are the thread libraries version info.

```
use threads; - installed v2.15 (latest - 2.16)
use Thread::Queue; - installed v3.12 (up to date)
use threads::shared; - installed v1.56 (latest - 1.57)
perl - installed v5.26.1
```

Other libraries are::

```
use YAML::XS 'LoadFile';  - 0.66 up to date
use Net::Netconf::Manager; - 1.02 up to date
use Config::Properties; - 1.80 up to date
use Sys::Syslog; - 0.35 up to date
use DateTime::Format::Strptime; - 1.74 up to date
use DateTime; - 1.44 up to date
use XML::LibXML; - 2.0129 (latest 2.0139)
use Regexp::Common qw/net/; - 2017060201 up to date
use Getopt::Long; - 2.5 up to date
```

Comment: We at least need to know what other libraries (with versions and perl version) you're using. But without a reproducible piece of code, we can't reliably answer.

Comment: Your screenshot mentions `Net::SSH2`: [About Net::SSH2 thread safety](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=936201)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To give you a firm answer, we need something we can run and troubleshoot. Otherwise the error is not reproducible.

Having said that - this looks like something similar to what I have encountered before with certain modules not being thread safe - they'll often run fine, and then very occasionally explode in your face.

E.g. [Crypt::SSLeay](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=41007) back in 2008. [Net::SSLeay](http://search.cpan.org/~mikem/Net-SSLeay-1.82/lib/Net/SSLeay.pod#Using_Net::SSLeay_in_multi-threaded_applications) prior to 1.4.2

The general workaround is to *stop* loading the culprits at compile time with `use` - because then the same state is inherited by all threads - and instead *within* the thread, load them at runtime with `require` and `import`. By doing this, you're isolating them - your threads will take *slightly* longer to start, but you shouldn't be spamming threads anyway in perl.

Or use a different module that is thread safe.

With your update and screenshot - `Net::SSH2` is mentioned - and that implies one of your other modules is pulling that in.

However [Net::SSH thread safey](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=936201) indicates that [libssh](https://www.libssh2.org/) might have some constraints on thread safety:

> Thread-safe: just don't share handles simultaneously

You don't explicitly mention using it, but it looks like it's being pulled in by another module. At a guess, that'll be `Net::Netconf::Manager`.

And as a second further guess - it might well be doing the 'share handles' because it doesn't realise it's being run in a thread.

So this module is the one I'd suggest isolating within the threads:

```
require 'Net::NetConf::Manager';
Net::NetConf::Manager -> import;
```

And do the instantiation within-thread.

As you're using a worker-threads model, this should be minimal overhead, and will mean that you're not hitting this problem.

But more generally - it's unwise to assume modules are thread safe unless they explicitly say they are. The major 'tripping' points are usually whenever any sort of resource sharing can be assumed/implied by the module, such as network sockets, file handles, database connections etc. Often a socket is created at instantiation (e.g. the point where you pass username/password) and having two threads trying to drive a socket concurrently is a potential race condition.

Comment: Thank you. I have added all the packages and their version info that I am using to my question. I haven't used any of the packages that you have mentioned in your answer. And you are right that this error will explode very occasionally. I'm really worried that what causes the issue!

Comment: Were you able to conclude anything?

Comment: From the module list, less than the screenshot of the error that indicates it's `libssh` that you're having problems with. And that `Net::Netconf::Manager` pulls in `Net::SSH2` as part of `Net::Netconf::Access::ssh`, which as documented caveats regarding thread safety. (Any module that has _no_ mention of thread safety, is unwise to assume is thread safe - `Net::Netconf::Manager` falls into this category. )

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm testing the isolation of the Net::Netconf::Manager module, but I'm not getting it right :(. My thread calls a subroutine with parameters. I am trying to put the lines you posted above just below the parameter assignment in the subroutine, but its not working as expected. Can you please help?

Comment: Are you available to answer? Thanks.

Comment: Ask a new question. Code will probably be needed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47092975/perl-how-to-make-a-library-specific-to-individual-threads/47119568#47119568