# Perl - How to make a library specific to individual threads

Tags: multithreading, perl, ssh, libssh2, ietf-netconf

I am writing a multi threaded script in perl. In which I am using a library `Net::Netconf::Manager` which inturn uses `Net::SSH2`. This Net::SSH2(libssh2) doesn't seem to be thread safe when 'shared handles' simulataneously.

I quote as in [libssh2 website](https://www.libssh2.org/)

**Thread-safe: just don't share handles simultaneously**

1. I am not sure what this "sharing handles" mean. Also I would like to know how to 'not share handles'.

When I run my script, occasionally i see error trace with backtrace and memory map denoting `*** glibc detected *** perl: double free or corruption (out): 0x00007f0320012d70 ***` error. This error is because of the thread safeness of the Net::SSh2 library.

2. How to make this Net::Netconf::Manager available to every thread instead of having it declared globally with '`use`' . I want all the threads to have their own access to this library independent of other threads.

Please let me know your views.

Comment: Didn't [Sobrique's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47074653/5830574) to your other question help? He wrote about `require` and `import` there. No offence, I'm just asking.

Comment: If the library isn't thread safe, loading it in the thread with `require` might help, but some libraries (e.g. [Tk](http://p3rl.org/Tk)) can't run in a thread at all.

Comment: It did not solve my problem. I wasn't able to successfully isolate this library with the way he mentioned. I tried and I did asked him in comment, but there was no response. Do you know how to isolate this library specific to threads?

Comment: @choroba sorry what do you mean by loading it in the thread? To load the library in the subroutine that the thread calls? with `require packagename`? What would be its scope? will it be specific to that subroutine or to the entire thread? Meaning - all the subroutines that are called in the thread will have access to this library?

Comment: @BalaKrishnan: Exactly. You might need to call `import` as well.

Comment: @choroba Same problem persists when I use require and import in the thread. I am having 4 threads. First two threads calls a sub - A, and the second two calls a sub - B. I have loaded this lib in both the subroutines. No help. Same error.

Comment: Try switching to forking instead of threads.

Comment: Finally, I used semaphores and synchronized the particular block which was causing the issue. Its kind of a workaround and does affect thread functionality a bit, but I do not want to move from threads. So. Maybe this issue will be fixed soon.

Comment: I can give a more complete answer with some sample code. But my suggestion remains - stop using `use` and instead `require` and `import` within the thread. This will _generally_ be safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am the current maintainer for `Net::SSH2`.

I have never went after thread safeness for that module but a shallow inspection of its code, shows that probably, that double free error is caused by the Perl side of the `Net::SSH2` objects being cloned on thread creation while the C side is not. That results in `libssh2` objects being destroyed and released twice which results in the program crashing.

So, if you want to use `Net::SSH2` in a multithread application you should ensure that threads are never created from threads where objects of this module exist.

Even then there may be other bugs lurking on the module.

Obviously the right thing to do would be to fix the module. If you want to do it yourself, I would try to help you. Just get in touch with me so that we could discuss the details first... Otherwise, now that you have brought that issue to my attention, well, probably at some point I will fix it myself... but this is not going to happen overnight.

Comment: sure. I'm glad to fix it myself. How could we get in touch? This is my email - balakrishnaneaswaran@gmail.com

Comment: @BalaKrishnan: I have created a new ticked on GitHub in order to keep the discussion in the open: [Object lifetime in multi-threading applications](https://github.com/rkitover/net-ssh2/issues/40).

Answer (score 3):

The general workaround to 'thread safety' problems is 'require' and 'import'. These must be called *after* any sort of thread instantiation takes place, and no threads may be created after (from wherever loaded the modules - it's ok within 'main').

So - because you haven't given us any code, I've used samples out of the module. You'll need to amend accordingly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use Thread::Queue;

my $num_workers = 10;

my %generalargs = (
   'access'              => 'ssh',
   'server'              => 'netconf',
   'command'             => 'junoscript netconf',
   'debug_level'         => 1,
   'client_capabilities' => [
      'urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0',
      'urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:capability:candidate:1.0',
      'urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:capability:confirmed-commit:1.0',
      'urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:capability:validate:1.0',
      'urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:capability:url:1.0?protocol=http,ftp,file',
      'http://xml.juniper.net/netconf/junos/1.0',
   ]
);

my @host_list = (
   {  'hostname' => 'routername',
      'login'    => 'loginname',
      'password' => 'secret',
   },
   {  'hostname' => 'routername2',
      'login'    => 'differentname',
      'password' => 'anotherpassword',
   },
);

my $work_q = Thread::Queue->new;


sub some_helper_sub_that_isnt_a_thread {
   my ( $input, $process ) = @_;
   return "$input";
}

sub do_netconf_stuff {
   require 'Net::NetConf::Manager';
   Net::NetConf::Manager->import;

   while ( my $item = work_q->dequeue ) {
      my $device = Net::NetConf::Manager->new( %{$item} );
      print 'Could not create Netconf device' unless $device;
      some_helper_sub($device);
   }
}

threads->create( \&do_netconf_stuff ) for 1 .. $num_workers;

foreach my $host (@host_list) {
   $work_q->enqueue( { %$host, %generalargs } );
}
$work_q->end;

$_->join for threads->list;
```

What happens here is that each thread independently - and at runtime - imports the `Net::NetConf::Manager` and that means they're each separately instantiated. You can then call other subs from within the thread, and they'll work fine - you've loaded into the global namespace *for that thread*.

The thing you must not do is then start additional threads that will 'inherit' that imported environment.

Note - this isn't 100% sure to work - there's other reasons that threads might clash (like trying to listen on the same port number, lock the same files etc.). But you will avoid problems within modules due to sharing of file handles etc.